# ckeditor error while creating file upload button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, fckeditor

I am using below code to create a `ckeditor` plugin to upload images. While i am trying to create a ckeditor dialog, I am getting below errors. Below piece of code i took from the below link.
http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.button.html

In chrome :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined

In firefox :

> b.getContentElement(...) is undefined

Any help will be greateful.

```
{
    type : 'file',
    id : 'upload',
    label : 'Select file from your computer',
    size : 38
},
{
    type : 'fileButton',
    id : 'fileId',
    label : 'Upload file',
    'for' : [ 'tab1', 'upload' ],
    filebrowser : {
        onSelect : function( fileUrl, data ) {
            alert( 'Successfully uploaded: ' + fileUrl );
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: did you tried anything? did you solved ?

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz I resolved it. in 'for' there were two values 'tab1' and 'upload'. Here the 'tab1' is the id of the parent tab which consist these buttons and 'upload' is the id of the button which is used as button to upload. But I assigned different id for the tab. I have assigned id for the tab as 'customtab' but here i mentioned it as 'tab1'. So it should be like 'for' : ['customtab','upload'].

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you have there, is not "code" as it.  Is just the object definition you must do to initialize a button in a dialog, as the docs you pasted say:

> This class is not really part of the API. It just illustrates the
>   properties that developers can use to define and create buttons.
>
> Once the dialog is opened, the created element becomes a
>   CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.button object and can be accessed with
>   CKEDITOR.dialog#getContentElement. For a complete example of dialog
>   definition, please check CKEDITOR.dialog.add.

Then, if we check that: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition

We will find this code:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'testOnly', function( editor ) {
    return {
        title:          'Test Dialog',
        resizable:      CKEDITOR.DIALOG_RESIZE_BOTH,
        minWidth:       500,
        minHeight:      400,
        contents: [
            {
                id:         'tab1',
                label:      'First Tab',
                title:      'First Tab Title',
                accessKey:  'Q',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type:           'text',
                        label:          'Test Text 1',
                        id:             'testText1',
                        'default':      'hello world!'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
} );
```

Then it seems you need to call the method `CKEDITOR.dialog.add` with the object you prepared. (anyway, I din´t checked all the data and the formats you have in your object) this example should work.

Anyway, you should check [this part of the same documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/source/plugin32.html#CKEDITOR-fileTools-fileLoader) and be sure on which one is the dialog/plugin you need.

Hope it may help to you.